# Is it possible to acquire raw IMU and RGB-D data with Google Tango?

Tags: google-project-tango

In my Lab, we are considering buying a Google Tango development kit. But first we would like to make sure that we can get what we need out of it. From what I could check online, it is possible to acquire the pose estimate calculated by the device, along with the point-clouds acquired by its RGB-D camera. However, so far I could not find any references to acquiring raw IMU data, meaning the raw values obtained from the device's accelerometers and gyroscopes. Ideally, the raw IMU and RGB-D data would be timestamped; so that the IMU values can be integrated between the timestamps of two consecutive RGB-D images.

Is this even possible?

Is there any existing code already doing this for Google Tango?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was talking to a colleague about this problem, and there are some Apps that already access the raw IMU data. As an example, the App [Sensorstream IMU+GPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.lorenz_fenster.sensorstreamgps&hl=en) can acquire this data.

It is not yet clear to me what Android API calls need to be used to acquire it. However, I am sure now that raw IMU data can be acquired at least in the devices that have a proper integration with Android, and I guess that this must be the case of the Google Tango.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get raw IMU or RGBD data via Project Tango API. From the API the only data you can query are 1.Poses as `TangoPoseData` objects, 2. RGB Image as either using a texture id or raw buffer and 3. Depth data in the form of point clouds. Ofcourse all of this data is timestamped which can be used to synchronize.

Comment: Ok, I see. It is good that the point cloud (RGB image + Depth image) can be acquired for further processing. This was very informative. I will still leave the question open, to see if more people corroborate that the IMU raw data is not available. Acquiring the raw data at a high rate (>= 50 Hz) could be very useful.